# why does a ground rod wire have to be continuous?

Tags: ground

my main panel (installed in 1976) has the grounding wire connected to a ¾" water pipe that runs at least 30' underground - no ground rod... I would like to add a ground rod to bring it up to code (not for any inspection - just to be safer in the event of a lightning strike) but I understand the grounding wire must be continuous to both ground rod and water pipe, or fused to the original grounding wire... it would be a huge hassle to run another longer continuous ground wire to the panel in the garage - I would have to remove a metal door frame, an exterior outlet and some trim boards under the eaves)... what would happen if I just connected the solid 6 ga wire from the new ground rod to the two-screw clamp (not acorn) at the water pipe, making sure both grounding wires are connected tight... I understand it probably won't pass an inspection - but this will not be inspected... wouldn't that be better than just having the single water pipe as ground?

although i could possibly drill a small hole through the plywood siding and run the grounding wire through the hole and up to the panel (in garage) from the inside of the wall where I can access the rear of the panel... but that would entail drilling a small hole in the rear of the panel near the bottom (where there is some space) to get the grounding wire inside the panel to the ground bus... the original bare grounding wire comes out underneath the siding at the foundation and runs along the bottom of the siding to the water pipe - so I assume running a bare grounding wire through a small hole in siding is no different than running it along the bottom of the siding... although perhaps drilling a small hole in the rear of the panel for the grounding wire is a no-no...

is there a way to splice the wires that would pass code without the whole 'nuclear' fusing thing?? I have a Temco TH0007 Hammer Lug Connector (see link below) that I've used for lugs when I was putting solar panels on top of my cargo trailer... would that be better using a 6 ga copper butt connector than just connecting the new ground rod 6 ga wire to the old existing water pipe clamp?

[Temco Hammer Lug Connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E1UUVT0)

Comment: Think it is because where there is a connection, there is resistance(heating).  When talking about lighting, it is possible for the extra resistance to destroy the connection, before the ground can finish doing it's job.

Comment: @crip659 code allows splices , see 250.64.C.1  splicing of wire type GEC shall be permitted by irreversible compression type connectors listed for grounding and bonding equipment  or by exothermic welding process.

Comment: The water pipe IS a code compliant electrode today! It only needs 10’ of earth , if the 20’ of copper was #2 it would classify as a ground electrode also see 250.52 .  I have used wire when on granite where I could not drive even a 3’ ground rod.

Comment: @crip659.  I understand how a mechanical connection may create resistance / heating (with corrosion?) and perhaps destroy the connection to ground, but isn't that precisely what you have with the grounding wire from the panel to the acorn nut (or two screw clamp) on the grounding rod? how is that not susceptible to the same resistance / heating / corrosion? and also the screw at the ground bus in the panel?

Comment: Think they are more worried about splices in between the two ends.  Your rod is ten feet away, but you only have two five foot pieces.   As @EdBeal stated there are only two  types allowed.

Comment: @crip659.  yes, it does appear the code is only worried about mechanical connections in-between the two ends - but no one can tell me why a mechanical connection at the ends is any different than a mechanical connection / splice in the middle of the grounding connector... is there no resistance / heating / corrosion possible between the wire and its mechanical connection to the ground rod at the acorn / 2 screw clamp? I can see how a loose mechanical connection in a splice between wires could cause a problem - but is it not the same with a loose connection at the acorn nut / 2 screw clamp?

Comment: Wow an acorn nut really where is the electrical connection?? I will step aside and let all the internet only electricians advise Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question a ground wire is required to be continuous but it can have irreversible compression splices or exothermic welded splices.

A listed compression splice for grounding is what you need (yes it will need to be listed for grounding & bonding) next it requires the proper crimp tool, these can be rented for a few $$ at many rental places.

Exothermic is not realistic for home use as the graphite blocks and cad weld material is much more than the cost of the wire for 1 job.

So a listed splice can easily extend your conductor creating a code legal continuous grounding electrode conductor as you need.

Comment: Michael, you might get away with using that hammer lug crimper?? But the crimp itself if not listed will fail the splice (inspectors do check this even on pros).  Yes you can drill through the electrical enclosure of your sub, but I would suggest drilling from the hot side to the outside. A slight error drilling from the outside to inside can teach how high speed drill bits can evaporate copper or aluminum buss bars.

Comment: found a Polaris IT-4, 4-14 AWG, CU9AL, 600 V, Wire Connector - will use that with some dialectric grease in the holes...

Comment: no one around here had any heavy duty irreversible compression butt connectors - supply chain issues...

Comment: Polaris is an absolute violation of code but go ahead and if there are future problems you have been advised of code I had a fire f that wired things to code 3-4 code cycles later there was a death he did won all it takes is 1 flagrant violation and something bad not even connected but it is your choice there is no such thing as heavy duty I never used those words I stated “listed for grounding and bonding” and 6awg is quite small but as I said good luck with a diy hack.

Comment: I can't fathom how my 'hack' can be any worse than a grounding wire to a 50 year old corroded copper water pipe... if I connect the Polaris to the end of the wire after the water pipe clamp (which by the way is also a simple mechanical reversible connection like the Polaris) and run a 6 ga wire 10 or 12 feet away and connect it to a real ground rod - how is that any worse than what I have now? how is a new Polaris with dialectic grease packed in the holes any worse than a 50 year old 2 screw clamp? no one here seems to be able to answer that - they just want to quote code...

Comment: It violates code simple, a hack is just that a hack. Also Polaris are more expensive than splices but it’s your place.

Answer (score 2):

The whole question stands on one misunderstanding: it's not required that *all the grounding electrodes* be daisy-chained onto a *single continuous grounding electrode conductor*. You can "home-run" a separate conductor for each grounding electrode - in other words, just add a new wire going only to the proposed ground rod. It is true, however, that each of those "grounding electrode conductors (GEC)" must be continuous (or irreversibly spliced, etc).

In case you happen to be thinking about conduit for cosmetics or to protect the GEC, there is one catch. When a GEC goes through ferrous conduit, like EMT or rigid steel, you have to use a bonding clamp at each end. If you have two GEC's then they must go through no conduit, non-ferrous conduit like PVC or aluminum, or each be in their own ferrous conduit with bonding clamps at the entry and exit of each conduit.

Comment: Greg did you win the lottery? Really parallel conductors from separate grounding points this is a Classic Internet only type of advice when the op was asking to reduce the copper.

Comment: @EdBeal It seemed OP was concerned about the hassle of running a new conductor that could visit both the ground rod and the water pipe locations. So I pointed out that they can simply run new wire to the new rod, leaving the existing wire to the water pipe alone (no need to upgrade/replace/touch that). Maybe I had misunderstood the physical layout -- it might be that in OP's case, the new rod is very near to the water pipe and so the hassle and cost of a new home-run conductor for the ground rod is the same as one that does both the water pipe and the ground rod.